# MongoDB - _id as String instead of ObjectId ? Relationship between collections or duplicate data?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, node.js

Scenario:
An entity called 'accessPoint' has an important attribute called 'network'. The application will display some parts of this network attribute, so I decided to store it inside accessPoint documents.

I also decided to store all networks documents (with additional attributes) in a separated collection (for performance reason: it will be used in an autocomplete input in the front end)

```
accessPoint: {
    id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    uptime: Number,
    network: {
        subnet: String,
        netmask: Number
    }
}

network: {
    _id: ObjectId
    subnet: String,
    netmask: Number,
    size: Number,
    validatedAt: Date,
    attrX: String,
    attrY: String,
    attrZ: String
}
```

I have 3 major questions:
1 - Is it a good practice to store networks in a separated colletion? (attention to the requirement above)

2 - Is there any compliance/convention issues building a relationship between these two documents (like an SQL DBMS)?

3 - And, I was wondering... can I store _id as String instead of ObjectId?
I've read some advices, but I don't have a conclusive opinion about it.
e.g : `... network: { _id: "192.168.1.0/24" }` (uniqueness guaranteed :D)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some clarifications to your questions:

> 1 - Is it a good practice to store networks in a separated colletion?
> (attention to the requirement above)

It depends upon your application functionality and the data.

One of the questions is what is the relationship between the two entities `accessPoint` and `network`? Is it One-to-One, One-to_Many or Many-to-Many.

The next question is, what are your significant queries? Which queries are accessed frequently and are important in terms of user experience, performance, etc.

In general, a One-to-One relationship should be modeled as a single document. That is `accessPoint` and `network` as one document. Note, each MongoDB document can store up to 16 MB of data.

A One-to-Many relationship can be modeled as a single entity, or as two entities. It is preferred that the related information is stored together - so that it can be accessed together.

> 2 - Is there any compliance/convention issues building a relationship
> between these two documents (like an SQL DBMS)?

The reference or relationship relates the two entities, in this case the `network` related info.

Ideally, it should be the unique field of the `network` entity. That means, store the `nework`entity's `_id` field (also) in the `network` sub-document within the `accessPoint`. This `network._id` can be used as a *reference* (or relationship) field.

MongoDB Aggregation Framework allows "join" queries between related collections - the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) aggregation stage allows this. So, if you need to access data from both collections as a single query use the `$lookup`.

Queries accessing a single collection can be formed easily and perform better than the aggregation queries using `$lookup`.

> 3 - And, I was wondering... can I store _id as String instead of
> ObjectId? I've read some advices, but I don't have a conclusive
> opinion about it. e.g : ... network: { _id: "192.168.1.0/24" }
> (uniqueness guaranteed :D)

`_id` field can be of any MongoDB BSON types, except an *array* field type. Other important things to note about the `_id` field are:

- It must be unique (there is a default and an immutable unique index on this field)
- It must be immutable (this field value cannot be updated or removed for a document).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to store networks in a separated colletion?
> (attention to the requirement above)

It depends on your app and how do you use them, but I can say collection design is okay.

> Is there any compliance/convention issues building a relationship
> between these two documents (like an SQL DBMS)?

Generally, No-SQL databases don't use for relationship collections.

> And, I was wondering... can I store _id as String instead of
> ObjectId? I've read some advices, but I don't have a conclusive
> opinion about it. e.g : ... network: { _id: "192.168.1.0/24" }
> (uniqueness guaranteed :D)

Yes, you can. BTW, uniqueness guaranteed by mongodb. Because `_id` field has a unique index by default.

```
db.inspections.insert({ "_id": "192.168.1.0/24", "test": 1 })
```

[image]

Comment: Thankss for clarification!!